# Conditional statement not working on ListTile onTap Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm trying to put a condition for image opener in my app. If `image` is `null` then it shouldn't do anything but if there is some image coming then it should open it in full screen image opener but its not working. I'm fetching data in `ListView.builder`. Not all images are going to be null from database because the image is optional so some images will be coming, some will be not I can't fetch them all and put them into the image viewer it'll show broken image view which I don't want.

Update: Debug log gives this when I tap on no image ListTile index

```
Image provider: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0)
```

[image: Printing snapshot giving this]

Here's my ListTile:

```
ListTile(
                        onTap: () async {
                          if (snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['image'] !=
                              null) {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ImageOpener(
                                      imageProvider: Image.network(
                                        snapshot.data?.docs[index]
                                            .data()['image'],
                                        errorBuilder:
                                            (context, error, stackTrrace) {
                                          return const Icon(Icons.error);
                                        },
                                      ).image,
                                    )));
                          } else if (snapshot.data?.docs[index]
                                  .data()['image'] ==
                             "") {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                const SnackBar(
                                    content: Text('No image to show')));
                          } else {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                const SnackBar(
                                    content: Text('No image to show')));
                          }
                        },
                        subtitle: Text(
                          snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['notificationbody'],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              // fontSize: 15,
                              ),
                        ),
                        title: Text(snapshot.data?.docs[index]
                                ['notificationtext'] ??
                            "Loading..."),
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                        trailing: Image.network(
                          snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['image'],
                          errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrrace) {
                            return const Visibility(
                              visible: false,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Icon(Icons.error),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: You can remove the else if. It's either null or not null. Then I would check if there is an empty string in image instead of null. I would also just print snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['image'] in the onTap above or use the debugger to see what is in the variable.

Comment: Its coming in string. Firebase storage url to be exact. If there is no image then upon printing it's giving empty string which I've attached in my question I've updated my condition too to check if string is empty its still not working

Comment: The first if condition is wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the image url is not empty (not null) and if it is not empty you can call your Navigator.push

```
if (snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['image'].isNotEmpty) {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ImageOpener(
                                      imageProvider: Image.network(
                                        snapshot.data?.docs[index]
                                            .data()['image'],
                                        errorBuilder:
                                            (context, error, stackTrrace) {
                                          return const Icon(Icons.error);
                                        },
                                      ).image,
                                    )));
                          }else{
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                const SnackBar(
                                    content: Text('No image to show')));
                          }
```